# ReactJs componentDidMount fetch URL overwriting form submit fetch URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api, lifecycle

In my component, it starts with a `componentDidMount()` lifecycle that fetches data to display on a table.

```
componentDidMount() {
        fetch(TABLE_DATA, { 
        //TABLE_DATA is a global variable that runs a callback which combines the rest of the variable
        //to the url. It's mostly for deployment; an easy way to change urls back and forth. 
            credentials: 'include',
            methods: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
            },
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data=>{
            this.setState({
                tableData: data,
                isLoaded: true
            })
        })
   }
```

Now when I want to submit some information on a form in the same component, for some reason, the TABLE_DATA variable overrides whatever url I'm fetching with.
Here is the code for submitting the form:

```
    submitAccountToUser= e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        fetch(EXTRA_INFO, {
            credentials: 'include',
            methods: 'POST',
            headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify({
                'info':this.state.info
            })
        })
        .then(res => console.log('res', res)) 
        //doesn't get to this console.log. It stops on the line with "fetch(EXTRA_INFO
    }
```

EXTRA_INFO is overwritten as TABLE_DATA. It shows on my local server/terminal that there is a 'GET' method being called at the TABLE_DATA url. Along with this error in my browser:

> **Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body.**

Which makes sense since the initial fetch call (`TABLE_DATA`) is only a 'GET' request and cannot have a body. But it shouldn't even be fetching for that URL.
I've kept it simple by looking for syntax errors and checking the URL's in my global variables. But I don't understand why it would completely ignore `EXTRA_INFO`'s value.

** **EDIT** **
The callback function that TABLE_DATA and EXTRA_INFO get their api's from looks like this:

```
const TABLE_DATA = backend_route('/tableinfo')

const backend_route = (route) => {
    const backend = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000'
    return backend + route
}
```

Comment: How are `TABLE_DATA` and `EXTRA_INFO` defined? (if you're concerned, you can obfuscate private details of the URLs)

Comment: @SebastianB. I edited the bottom of my post to answer your question. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be on my submit fetch method.
I had **'methods'**, instead of **'method'**.

Silly me. But I found it weird how react responded to that error